# Video is not downloading HTML video tag

Tags: html, video, html5-video

```
<video id="vidNew" class="video" controls="controls" poster="../new/image/happynewyear.png" src="../new/img/bye.mp4">
</video>
```

The video is opening fine but clicking the download option is just play/pausing the video.

Comment: Do you have any more code to share? How can we reproduce this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That `controls="controls"` should be just `controls`. Try a test without `poster` entry and also use proper full path in video `src` eg: `src="https://example.com/new/img/bye.mp4`. If still not working then give us a link to your demo test page for analysis.